# No Such Instance currently exists at this OID snmpset

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I am trying to set some OID but seems that it gives below error "**No Such Instance currently exists at this OID**" which should not be the case as i am able to get/walk same OID. so its present.

```
root@m-snm:~# snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 10.2.4.19 .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.7.3
iso.3.6.1.x.x.x.x.x.7.3 = INTEGER: 1
root@m-snm:~# snmpset -v 2c -c public 10.2.4.19 .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.7.3 i 2
iso.3.6.1.x.x.x.x.x.7.3 = **No Such Instance currently exists at this OID**
root@m-snm:~# snmpget -v 2c -c public 10.2.4.19 .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.7.3
iso.3.6.1.x.x.x.x.x.7.3 = INTEGER: 1
```

Is it the permission issue ? Or i am not allowed to write ? or the field itself is not writable ? how can check what field are r/w and what are readonly

Comment: Why did you hide OIDs? How are we supposed to help you out not knowing anything about the objects you are trying to change? Is it a tabular object instance or scalar object? You have not provided enough information.

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin updated the details

Comment: Ok you are trying to change the admin status of interface with index=3. It should work. The only reason for such error would be invalid community name or agent implementation restrictions/limitations. Are you sure your write community string is public?

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin yes i m using public as community string also tried private
 i m doing same thing interface is for index=3 only ...is my command wrong?

Comment: What is your target device (vendor, model)? Have you configured write community on device? Have you enabled write access on device? Please note some devices like Juniper switches do not allow changing admin status via SNMP.

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin  its an snmp simulator, i donot have much details about its configuration ( was done by somebody else ) is there a way to checck write access enabled/disabled may be by some commands

Comment: There are many SNMP simulators on the market. Is it some sort of home grown app or commercial simulator?